# social sharing authorized page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to implement social sharing of a set of static pages. But the pages need authorization. Requirement being:

1. People who are redirected from social site should be able to see the content of the page.
2. Others shouldn't until they login on our site.

what is the best way to implement this?

Comment: What authentication system are you using atm? I recommend using IdentityServer4 if you aren't yet using, even with that you may need some sort of consent from user that you will access their data via other identity service provider (google, facebook, etc.)

Comment: Thank you @AD8 
Since the data need to be tacked. We are using a different action to take care of this.